# Django: How to create an instance of a list of multiple objects and display on admin page

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

So say for example, I have a model Student:

```
class product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def _str_(self):
        return self.name
```

And I want to create a recommendation list (a list that contains product objects) that allow super user to select products from the built in admin page.

My question is, is creating a separate model (`class recommendation(models.Model)`)and using ForeignKey a correct approach to this situation? Because I do not consider recommendation a model, but I do want super user to be able access and manipulate the list on admin page.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct approach in this situation would be to set up a recommendation model, but with a many to many relationship. This will allow you to add many products to a specific recommendation, while allowing a product to be used in many recommendations. The set up for this will look something like this:

```
class Recommendation(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField('Product')
```

Setting up the model like this will also allow you to explore other features such as adding an owner of a recommendation